# vue js in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-router

i am implementing vue js in bootstrap html template... problem i am facing is in navbar..

my code is

```
<router-link tag="li" to="#">
     <a><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="nav-label">Syllabus</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
     <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
         <router-link tag="li" to="/syllabus 1">
                <a> Syllabus</a>
         </router-link>
         <router-link tag="li" to="/syllabus/topic">
                <a>Syllabus Topic</a>
         </router-link>
      </ul>
 </router-link>
```

i have also tried using

```
<li>
         <a><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="nav-label">Syllabus</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
         <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
             <router-link tag="li" to="/syllabus">
                    <a> Syllabus 1</a>
             </router-link>
             <router-link tag="li" to="/syllabus/topic">
                    <a>Syllabus Topic</a>
             </router-link>
          </ul>
 </li>
```

but the problem is when i am reloading the page the menu collapse and expands normally as it should work but when i am clicking on a a sub menu for instance "syllabus1" the page redirects to syllabus but the menu freezes and does not any longer collapse or expands...then again on reloading the menu starts working fine

please help me with this... thanks in advance... please provide an example in jsfiddle if possible... thankx..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45108393/392102

Answer (score 0):

First modify your router-link like this (notice the `@click.native` part and using router-link as `a` tag)

```
<router-link to="/syllabus 1" @click.native="closeMenu($event)">
```

Then in your main app, create a function called `collapse` with the following code

```
let app = new Vue({
   methods: {
      closeMenu($event) {
          $($event.currentTarget).closest('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
      }    
   }
});
```

This should do the trick!