# align content with bootstrap strange behaviour

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vue.js

I am working with vuejs and bootstrap so I am calling different components and attach them inside my HTML dynamically.

My problem is I don't get the desired effect, at the moment I have this:

[image]

the section title gives too much space related to the input and I don't know why the section is a different component and the data at the bottom gets loaded dynamically depending on the select box choice.

the rows columns and cells are a horizontal form but it occupies all the width of my row, I want the inputs to be lower and the button at centre a little bigger, I can't set it like I want if I try for example to increase button it will not be at centre anymore.

So here is my code:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <h1 class="text-center">Document Creation</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 margin-above">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Section</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" v-model="currentView">
                            <option v-for="(item,index) in sections" :value="item.key">{{item.text}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Here we load the diferent sections based on the selection choice -->
        <component v-bind:is="currentView">
            <!-- component changes when vm.currentView changes! -->
        </component>
    </div>
</template>
```

**inside the component the other component that has the rows and cells and columns get loaded like this:**

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-4">
            <form class="form-inline margin-above">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="rows">rows:</label>
                    <input type="number" min="1" value="1" class="form-control" id="rows">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="columns">columns:</label>
                    <input type="number" min="1" value="1" class="form-control" id="cols">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cells">cells:</label>
                    <input type="number" min="1" value="1" class="form-control" id="cols">
                </div>
                <div class="text-center"> 
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success margin-above2">Add Table</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Please, I need some help trying to display it correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're using too many `<div>`s for the layout. We can strip a few out to not only simplify the design, but also make it alot easier to read. We also want to leverage the use of bootstrap's [Horizontal Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)
.

Your first snippet would look like this:

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Document Creation</h1>
    <div class="col-md-12 form-horizontal margin-above">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label col-sm-1">Section</label>
         <div class="col-sm-11">
            <select class="form-control" v-model="currentView">
                <option v-for="(item,index) in sections" :value="item.key">{{item.text}}</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Here we load the diferent sections based on the selection choice -->
    <component v-bind:is="currentView">
    <!-- component changes when vm.currentView changes! -->
    </component>
</div>
<template>
```

And your second would look like this:

```
<template>
     <form class="margin-above">
         <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label for="rows" class="control-label">rows:</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" value="1" class="form-control" id="rows">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
             <label for="columns" class="control-label">columns:</label>
             <input type="number" min="1" value="1" class="form-control" id="cols">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
             <label for="cells" class="control-label">cells:</label>
             <input type="number" min="1" value="1" class="form-control" id="cols">
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-12 margin-above text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success margin-above2">Add Table</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

I've made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3rf6yn0c/) to show the snippets together.

Comment: seems good thank you, but just a thing i want to place the row, cells and column side by side not vertical

Answer (score 0):

You are going to run into problems [trying to use Boostrap and Vue together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45108393/392102), but that is a question for another day.

By carefully mimicking the [examples here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#examples), you can get a more nicely-spaced `section` layout.

```
<div class="margin-above form-group row">
  <label class="col-form-label col-sm-1">
    Section
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <select class="form-control" v-model="currentView">
      <option v-for="(item,index) in sections" :value="item.key">{{item.text}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Making the button bigger is just a matter of adding one of the sizing classes. It does not cause a problem for centering:

```
      <div class="text-center margin-above2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Add Table</button>
      </div>
```

Putting some extra space in is some ordinary CSS. Here it is as a snippet. Depending on your display size, you may need different `col-*-#` classes.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentView: 'doesNotMatter',
    sections: [{
      label: 'one'
    }, {
      label: 'two'
    }]
  },
  components: {
    someComponent: {}
  }
});
```

```css
.margin-above2 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <h1 class="text-center">Document Creation</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="margin-above form-group row">
      <label class="col-form-label col-sm-1">
        Section
      </label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control" v-model="currentView">
          <option v-for="(item,index) in sections" :value="item.key">{{item.text}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Here we load the diferent sections based on the selection choice -->
  <some-component inline-template>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rows">rows:</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" value="1" class="form-control" id="rows">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="columns">columns:</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" value="1" class="form-control" id="cols">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cells">cells:</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" value="1" class="form-control" id="cells">
          </div>
          <div class="text-center margin-above2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Add Table</button>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </some-component>
</div>
```